# Python regex to match 3 consecutive characters in the alphabet but not necessarily side by side

Tags: python, regex, passwords

I have to build a python function that uses regex to check the complexity of a password which should have at least 8 characters, contains digits, letters and special symbols and last rules (the hardest) : not contain three consecutive letters or three consecutive digits.
To illustrate the last rule : `Mz2a%yc98B` will not be accepted since it contains 3 consecutives letters : aBc

I did well for the first two rules but I have no clue of what can I do for the last rule. It's pretty complex I think. Some people told me that's impossible to do that using regex but actually it has to be possible or it's crazy no ?

Thank you very much !

My code so far :

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"")
while True:
    password = input("Enter your password")
    if re.match(r"(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=(.*[!%@$#&^*()\-__+.]){1,})(?=.*[0-9]).{8,}", password):
        result = pattern.match(password)
        print("Your password is strong enough")
    else:
        print("Your password is not strong enough")
```

And also in the example password I gave yes they are aBc, the B is the last characters.
And it's just an example. When I mean consecutives, I mean consecutive in the alphabet. If for example efg letters are used even spreaded in the password, it must detect it.
Thanks

Comment: You'll need a lot more programming logic to go along with your regex, as there's no way to do this all in one go. At least, that I'm aware of...

Comment: Can show the code you already have? I guess there is a typo in your password, because there is no `aBc`

Comment: @Rabinzel the way I read it, there can't be `abc` in the entire password, regardless of order. Hopefully that's wrong.

Comment: ooooh consecutive isn't related to the password, more to the alphabet ? I read it different, would be good to know if OP could make that clear....reading it again, probably you are right @MattDMo , it makes more sense

Comment: is this regex maybe what you are looking for? for the characters at least? ([A-z]{3})|([0-9]{3})

Comment: @alexander that just matches 3 letters or 3 numbers. Not what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @MattDMo yeah, it matches 3 consecutive numbers/letters.  he can just check for a regex match and if there is one, he knows its a failed p/w

Comment: You don't have to build one single regex pattern to solve that right ? if the exercise is to write a function, you can just do several checks on the different tasks. First check the length and maybe the existence of all necessary characters (letters symbols and digits) and in the last step this 3 consecutive thingy

Comment: MattDMo yes you're right. Sorry if it wasnt clear, actually even myself I didnt understand the task the first time I read it. It seems quite complex I really don't know how we can do that using regex

Comment: @CitronWorld are you allowed to use 3rd-party modules? I've come up with a solution using sets, but in order to generate the 3-char strings for comparison I need [`more_itertools.windowed`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/more_itertools/more.html#windowed)...

Comment: I think I can. Yes Im interested seeing your solution, thanks

Comment: You ask if your teacher is crazy. Even if we knew him/her that would call for an opinion, which is a no-no at SO.

Comment: Your question would be clearer if the title were "Python regex to ensure that a string does not contain 3 digits or 3 letters that are consecutive", and the body were reworded accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ask  if it is *possible* to do that with a regular expression? Certainly! Is it pretty? That's in the eye of the beholder.

You need a regular expression that looks like this (with the case-indifferent flag set):

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[<special symbols here>])(?!<no 3 digits that are consecutive>)(?!<no three letters that are consecutive>).{8}
```

Let's look at the *negative lookahead*

```
(?!<no 3 digits that are consecutive>)
```

We can write that as follows.

```
(?!(?:(?=.*0)(?=.*1)(?=.*2))|(?:(?=.*1)(?=.*2)(?=.*3))|(?:(?=.*2)(?=.*3)(?=.*4))|(?:(?=.*3)(?=.*4)(?=.*5))|(?:(?=.*4)(?=.*5)(?=.*6))|(?:(?=.*5)(?=.*6)(?=.*7))|(?:(?=.*6)(?=.*7)(?=.*8))|(?:(?=.*7)(?=.*9)(?=.*9)))
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/IbRzv5/1)

The expression can be written in *verbose* mode (`re.X` or `re.VERBOSE`) to make it self-documenting.

```
(?!          # begin negative lookahead       
  (?:        # begin non-capture group
    (?=.*0)  # match > 0 characters followed by 0 (positive lookahead) 
    (?=.*1)  # match > 0 characters followed by 1 
    (?=.*2)  # match > 0 characters followed by 2
  )          # end non-capture group
  |          # or
  ... similar for (?:(?=.*1)(?=.*2)(?=.*3))
  ...
)            # end negative lookahead
```

The construction of

```
(?!<no three letters that are consecutive>)
```

is similar (containing an alternation with 23 elements, `a`, `b` and `c` to `x`, `y` and `z`).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution to the third criterion of your problem set.

```
import string
from more_itertools import windowed

alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase
numbers = string.digits

passwords = ["Mz2a%yc98B", "a1b2g3D!", "Tr0ub4dor?"]

def find_triplets(charset: set, target: str) -> bool:
    if len(charset) < 3:
        return False
    else:
        chars = "".join(sorted(charset))
        triplets = ["".join(tpl) for tpl in windowed(chars, 3)]
        return any(triplet in target for triplet in triplets)

for pwd in passwords:
    # we use sets to get rid of duplicatess
    alpha = set()
    nums = set()
    for char in pwd:
        if char.isalpha():
            alpha.add(char.lower())
        elif char.isdigit():
            nums.add(char)
        else:
            pass # we don't care about symbols here
    if find_triplets(alpha, alphabet) or find_triplets(nums, numbers):
        print(f"Your password {pwd} contains 3 consecutive letters or numbers")
    else:
        print(f"Your password {pwd} is good enough, I guess")
```

After the setup code, we first define a function to generate 3-character strings (`triplets`) from the input `charset`, after it has been sorted and turned into a string itself. This uses the [`windowed()`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/more_itertools/more.html#windowed) function from the very helpful 3rd party [`more_itertools`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) module. The function returns `True` if it finds any triplets that match a consecutive sequence in the `target` string, and `False` if it doesn't. Simple enough.

Next, we iterate over our list of passwords (you used [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) in your code, which is fine). First, we iterate over the password string character by character and add them to the appropriate set (lowercased in the case of alphabetic characters). We then call our `find_triplets()` function to test for consecutive runs of letters or numbers, and print a message accordingly.

You'll obviously want to change some of this to fit into your assignment, but I'll leave that up to you.

There is another method using [`re.search()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search), but I think `any(triplet in target for triplet in triplets)` is a lot more Pythonic.